# Congruence for Bernoulli numbers

Tags: congruences, bernoulli-numbers

It appears that for every odd prime $p$, the following congruence holds for Bernoulli numbers:
$$
2pB_{p-1}-pB_{2p-2}\equiv p-1\mod p^2\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}.
$$
The weaker statement that $2pB_{p-1}-pB_{2p-2}\equiv -1\mod p\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ follows from the von Staudt-Claussen Theorem. I am aware of the Kummer congruences, but they don't seem to apply here as the indices of the Bernoulli numbers in question are divisible by $p-1$.

> How does one prove this congruence modulo $p^2$?

Comment: how do you define the Bernouilli numbers ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Recursive_definition

Comment: I usually take the generating function as the definition. But I'm happy to use another definition if it makes the proof easier.

Comment: yes, as in the Fermat little theorem proof, most of the ${m \choose k}$ are $0$ modulo $p^2$

Comment: Is my solution correct? Claim $(1)$ may be wrong. Nice question. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof goes like this:

We have the following explicit formula for Bernoulli numbers:
$$ B_n= \sum_{ 0\le i \le n} \frac{ 1}{i+1}  \sum_{ 0\le j \le i}(-1)^j\binom{i}{j}j^n. \tag{1} $$
and the following explicit formula for Stirling numbers of second kind :
$$ \begin{Bmatrix}n\\i\end{Bmatrix}i!=(-1)^i \sum_{ 0\le j \le i} (-1)^j\binom{i}{j}j^n . \tag{2}$$
Now let $p$ be an odd prime and $1\le j \le p-1$, by Wilson theorem and Fermat little theorem, 
$$w_p=\frac{ (p-1)!+1}{p}, q_p(j)=\frac{ j^{p-1}-1}{p}, r_p(j)=\frac{ j^{2p-2}-1}{p}$$ are integers. Also we have a known congruence for the Harmonic number: $$H_{p-1}= \sum_{ 1\le i \le p-1} \frac{ 1}{i} \equiv 0  \mod p. \tag{3} $$

Then $$ B_{p-1}= \sum_{ 0\le i \le {p-1}} \frac{ 1}{i+1}  \sum_{ 0\le j \le i}(-1)^j\binom{i}{j}j^{p-1}. \tag{4} $$
 $$ B_{p-1}= \sum_{ 1\le i \le {p-2}} \frac{ 1}{i+1}  \sum_{ 1\le j \le i}(-1)^j\binom{i}{j}(p \cdot q_p(j)+1) +\frac{ 1}{p} \sum_{ 0\le j \le p-1}(-1)^j\binom{p-1}{j}j^{p-1} . \tag{5} $$
 $$ B_{p-1}= \sum_{ 1\le i \le {p-2}} \frac{ 1}{i+1}  \sum_{ 1\le j \le i}(-1)^j\binom{i}{j}(p \cdot q_p(j)+1) +\frac{ 1}{p} \begin{Bmatrix}{p-1}\\{p-1}\end{Bmatrix}(p-1)! . \tag{6} $$
 $$ p\cdot B_{p-1}\equiv  p\cdot \sum_{ 1\le i \le {p-2}} \frac{ 1}{i+1}  \sum_{ 1\le j \le i}(-1)^j\binom{i}{j} +(p-1)! \pmod {p^2}. \tag{7} $$
 $$ p\cdot B_{p-1}\equiv   -p\cdot \sum_{ 1\le i \le {p-2}} \frac{ 1}{i+1}  +(p-1)! \pmod {p^2}. \tag{8} $$
 $$ p\cdot B_{p-1}\equiv   -p\cdot H_{p-1} +p  +(p-1)! \pmod {p^2}. \tag{9} $$
 $$ p\cdot B_{p-1}\equiv    p  +(p-1)! \pmod{p^2} . \tag{10} $$
On the other hand 
$$ B_{2p-2}= \sum_{ 0\le i \le {2p-2}} \frac{ 1}{i+1}  \sum_{ 0\le j \le i}(-1)^j\binom{i}{j}j^{2p-2}. \tag{11} $$
 $$ B_{2p-2}= \sum_{\array{1\le i \le {2p-2}\cr i\neq p-1  }} \frac{ 1}{i+1}  \sum_{ 1\le j \le i}(-1)^j\binom{i}{j}(p \cdot r_p(j)+1) +\frac{ 1}{p} \sum_{ 1\le j \le p-1}(-1)^j\binom{p-1}{j}j^{2p-2} . \tag{12} $$
 $$ p\cdot B_{2p-2}\equiv  p\cdot \sum_{ \array{1\le i \le {2p-2}\cr i\neq p-1  }} \frac{ 1}{i+1}  \sum_{ 1\le j \le i}(-1)^j\binom{i}{j} + \sum_{ 1\le j \le p-1}(-1)^j\binom{p-1}{j}j^{2p-2}\pmod {p^2}. \tag{13} $$
 $$ p\cdot B_{2p-2}\equiv  -p\cdot \sum_{ \array{1\le i \le {2p-2}\cr i\neq p-1  }} \frac{ 1}{i+1}  + \sum_{ 1\le j \le p-1}(-1)^j\binom{p-1}{j}(p \cdot r_p(j)+1) \pmod {p^2}. \tag{14} $$
 $$ p\cdot B_{2p-2}\equiv  -p\cdot \sum_{ \array{1\le i \le {2p-2}\cr i\neq p-1  }} \frac{ 1}{i+1}  + \sum_{ 1\le j \le p-1}(-1)^j\binom{p-1}{j}p \cdot r_p(j) -1 \pmod {p^2}. \tag{15} $$
 $$ p\cdot B_{2p-2}\equiv  -p\cdot \sum_{ \array{1\le i \le {2p-2}\cr i\neq p-1  }} \frac{ 1}{i+1}  + \sum_{ 1\le j \le p-1}p \cdot r_p(j) -1 \pmod {p^2}. \tag{16} $$
 $$ p\cdot B_{2p-2}\equiv  -p\cdot \sum_{ \array{1\le i \le {2p-2}\cr i\neq p-1  }} \frac{ 1}{i+1}  + \sum_{ 1\le j \le p-1}j^{2p-2} -p \pmod {p^2}. \tag{17} $$
 $$ p\cdot B_{2p-2}\equiv  p + \sum_{ 1\le j \le p-1}j^{2p-2} -p \pmod {p^2}. \tag{18} $$
 $$ p\cdot B_{2p-2}\equiv  p + 2(p-1)!+1 \pmod {p^2}. \tag{19} $$

$(16)$ is obtained from $(15)$ since $$ \binom{p-1}{j} \equiv (-1)^j \pmod {p} . \tag{20}$$

$(18)$ is obtained from $(17)$ since $$\sum_{ \array{1\le i \le {2p-2}\cr i\neq p-1  }} \frac{ 1}{i+1} \equiv -1 \pmod {p}. \tag{21} $$
proof:
$$\sum_{\array{1\le i \le {2p-2}\cr i\neq p-1}}\frac{ 1}{i+1}=\sum_{1\le i \le p-2}(\frac{ 1}{i+1}+\frac{ 1}{p+i+1})+\frac{1}{p+1} \equiv 2\sum_{1\le i \le p-2}\frac{ 1}{i+1} +1  \pmod {p}.$$
$$\sum_{\array{1\le i \le {2p-2}\cr i\neq p-1}}\frac{ 1}{i+1} \equiv 2\cdot H_{p-1}-2 +1 \equiv -1 \pmod {p}.$$

$(19)$ is obtained from $(18)$ since $$\sum_{1\le j \le {p-1}} j^{2p-2} \equiv p+1 +2(p-1)! \pmod {p^2}. \tag{22} $$
proof:
let $1\le j,k \le {p-1}$.

$p\cdot r_p(j\cdot k) +1=j^{2p-2}k^{2p-2}=(p\cdot r_p(j) +1)(p\cdot r_p(k) +1) $ 
$p\cdot r_p(j\cdot k) \equiv p(r_p(j) + r_p(k)) \pmod {p^2}.$

$p\cdot r_p((p-1)!) \equiv \sum_{1\le j \le {p-1}}p \cdot r_p(j)  \pmod {p^2}.$
$p\cdot r_p(p\cdot w_p -1) \equiv \sum_{1\le j \le {p-1}}j^{2p-2} -p +1  \pmod {p^2}.$
$ (p\cdot w_p -1)^{2p-2}-1 \equiv \sum_{1\le j \le {p-1}}j^{2p-2} -p +1  \pmod {p^2}.$
$ 1-\binom{2p-2}{1}\cdot p\cdot w_p -1 \equiv \sum_{1\le j \le {p-1}}j^{2p-2} -p +1  \pmod {p^2}.$
$ 2(p-1)! +2 \equiv \sum_{1\le j \le {p-1}}j^{2p-2} -p +1  \pmod {p^2} \square$

Eventually the congruence 
$$2p\cdot B_{p-1} -p\cdot B_{2p-2} \equiv p-1  \pmod {p^2}. \tag{23} $$
is easily obtained from $(10)$ and $(19)$.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo $p^2$,
$\begin{align}2pB_{p-1}-pB_{2p-2}&\equiv 2\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{p-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{2p-2}\tag 1\\
&\equiv p-1-\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(k^{p-1}-1)^2\\
&\equiv p-1\tag3
\end{align}$

$(1)$ By Faulhaber formula and Von Staudt-Clausen theorem

$(2)$ By Fermat little theorem